# Downgrading from El Capitan to Yosemite

Tags: mac, osx-yosemite, osx-el-capitan

I need to downgrade mac os x on one computer, from El Capitan to Yosemite.
No Time Machine backups were done so i need to go with the os x bootable installer.

The problem is Yosemite does not appear anymore in the "purchased" tab in the app store application.

I could get a Yosemite installer from another Mac though, so the question is- will yosemite installer from another Mac do the work here? Or is it meant to be used only on that other Mac?

Comment: The installer will work on any machine - but with no backup, you will lose your existing data, there is no way to downgrade in-situ, only nuke & pave.

Comment: Yes thats no problem for me. Data on that Mac is no longer important.

Comment: The Yosemite installer will work fine on another machine